# How do I stop VLC Media Player from hiding my mouse cursor?

Tags: vlc-media-player

How do I stop VLC Media Player from hiding my mouse cursor? VLC hides my mouse cursor whenever I put my cursor over the video. It's very annoying.

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit and VLC Media Player 2.2.2 from the repos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Advanced Preferences** -> **Video** you'll see the entry to control this:-

[image: VLC Advanced Preferences]

**Hide cursor and fullscreen controller after x milliseconds** can be set to any large value longer than any video. Of course you'll retain the controller, but that comes with the setting.

Comment: How do I get to the VLC Advanced Preferences? I only see regular Preferences.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the screen: select **All** under **Show settings**.

Comment: Still hides the cursor in non-fullscreen videos (Ubuntu 16.04.2, VLC 2.2.2), where it is even more annoying. In fullscreen I'd actually expect it to hide, but not in window mode.

Comment: Actually there is a bug for the thing I was talking about: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1601981

Comment: @Zelphir - Thanks for the link: useful information. Not sure what you can do about it, apart from running an earlier version until a fix is released.

Comment: The workaround (setting timeout to the higher value) worked for me only after restarting vlc.

Comment: For anyone still annoyed by this in 2024: On Ubuntu, for me it only happens if I open a second video by double-clicking the file and it starts playing in an already open VLC window.

Opening any dialog window of VLC (for example the "Adjustments and Effects" in the bottom tool bar) then makes the mouse pointer permanently visible.

Or always close the VLC window and always start a new one for a new video

Answer (score 2):

The mouse also disappears in Windows if you have Tools | Preferences | Interface Settings | Video set to output: **OpenGL video output**. You need to set that to **OpenGL video output for Windows**